# Scheduled reminders question?

Tags: macos, reminders

Are scheduled reminders supposed to show up in Calendar.app if both are using icloud?

PS: iOS 7.0.4, OSX Mavericks

Answer (score 1):

Calendar.app and Reminders.app are distincts apps. They do not share their data even when stored on the cloud.

So no, Calendar won't show you reminders.